# Difference between URL.openConnection() and URLConnection.connect()?

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

In the code:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)createMerchURL.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
connection.addRequestProperty("Name", "Value1");

connection.connect();

..
connection.disconnect();
```

- When is the connection getting opened actually? At `..createMerchURL.openConnection();` ? or at `connection.connect();`?
- How can I set URL in the `connection` Object and use it with `connection.connect()`?(as I am less comfortable with `.openConnection()`)

Finally, is there any difference between the two?

Thanks..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> When is the connection getting opened actually? At ..createMerchURL.openConnection(); ? or at connection.connect();?

The latter. The former just parses the URL, finds the protocol, and creates the `HttpURLConnection` object.

> How can I set URL in the connection Object

You can't.

> and use it with connection.connect()?

You can't.

> (as I am less comfortable with .openConnection())

Bad luck: get comfy with it.

Comment: `Bad luck: get comfy with it.` hahaha..the best part :p even after 3 years. Thanks to Rx and Retrofit/OkHttp I moved on :D

Answer (score 8):

`connection.connect()` is not required. Operations that depend on being connected, like `getContentLength(), getResponseCode()` will implicitly perform the connection if necessary.

Source: [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#connect())

Comment: All true but doesn't answer either of the questions he asked.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, if you just want to trigger some PHP File (via `GET`) in some address, you can simply use `connect()` after `openConnection()`, and then `disconnect()` of course.